# Avoid query duplication when 'IN list' which empty and non empty list

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, jdbctemplate

```
  public static final String UPDATE_DOCUMENTS_WITH_TO_DELETE_FLAG_FOR_USER_SQL = "\n" +
          "UPDATE document d \n" +
          "SET d.indexed = :flagValue \n" +
          "WHERE d.user_id = :userId \n" +
          "AND d.to_delete = :toDelete";

  public static final String UPDATE_DOCUMENTS_WITH_TO_DELETE_FLAG_FOR_USER_WITH_EXCEPTIONS_SQL = "\n" +
          "UPDATE document d \n" +
          "SET d.indexed = :flagValue \n" +
          "WHERE d.user_id = :userId \n" +
          "AND d.to_delete = :toDelete \n" +
          "AND d.id NOT IN (:exceptForDocuments)";


  public int markUserDocumentsToDeleteAsUnindexed(String userId,Collection<String> exceptForDocuments) {
    Map<String,Object> params = Maps.newHashMap();
    params.put("flagValue",false);
    params.put("userId",userId);
    params.put("toDelete",1);
    params.put("exceptForDocuments",exceptForDocuments);
    if ( exceptForDocuments.isEmpty() ) {
      return jdbcTemplate.update(UPDATE_DOCUMENTS_WITH_TO_DELETE_FLAG_FOR_USER_SQL, params);
    }
    else {
      return jdbcTemplate.update(UPDATE_DOCUMENTS_WITH_TO_DELETE_FLAG_FOR_USER_WITH_EXCEPTIONS_SQL,params);
    }
  }
```

Is there a way to use a single query to perform both updates?

Because actually using the `UPDATE_DOCUMENTS_WITH_TO_DELETE_FLAG_FOR_USER_WITH_EXCEPTIONS_SQL` query seems to work against H2, but not MySQL. 
Any idea to avoid this query duplication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is likely because not every driver can handle parameterized arrays/collections.  If you have complete control over the `exceptForDocuments` contents, you can serialize it to SQL yourself (with simple sanitization checks) and then conditionally append it without using parameters.